# Open a Bootstrap Modal to edit a record in Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a "user" model. I have a list of users on the user index page with an edit button beside each. I want to click on the edit button for each user which will open a bootstrap modal.

On the bootstrap modal I want to display the user record which I can edit. The edit form will be from a _form.html.erb partial which will be used for the new and edit user controller methods.

When I click the update button, I want the modal form to update the record, close the modal and update the index page with the updated record.

**Issues**

1. Every time I click on the edit link the modal opens and displays the _forms partial but it is for a new record, not the record I want to edit. I think this is because rails runs the @user.persisted? helper which responds with false so it uses the "create" method in the user controller instead of the "edit" method.
2. The bootstrap modal does not close when I save the record.

Can you tell me how to get this to work?

**user/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@user, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <% if @user.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <br>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :company %>
      <br>
      <%= f.text_field :company %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <br>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**users/create.js.erb**

```
$(".usersTable").replaceWith("<%=j render :partial=> 'users/update_user', :locals => {users: @users }%>");
$("input[type=text]").val("");

$('#myModal').modal('hide');
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

**users/index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Listing users</h1>

<table class="usersAll">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="usersTable">
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user.name %></td>
        <td><%= user.company %></td>
        <td><%= user.email %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit',  '#', 'data-target' => '#myModal', 'data-toggle' => 'modal'  %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Add User
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= render 'users/form' %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**/controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end


  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)

        format.js {}
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current form is not for editing the record, change it to:

**users/index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Listing users</h1>

<table class="usersAll">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="usersTable">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user.name %></td>
        <td><%= user.company %></td>
        <td><%= user.email %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
        <td>
          <%= link_to 'Edit',  '#', 'data-target' => "#myModal_#{user.id}", 'data-toggle' => 'modal'  %>
          <div class="modal fade" id='<%= "myModal_#{user.id}" %>' tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <%= render 'users/form', user: user %>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
              </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
          </div><!-- /.modal -->
        </td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Add User
</button>
```

**user/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(user, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <% if @user.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <br>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :company %>
      <br>
      <%= f.text_field :company %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <br>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

If you want clicking the submit to refresh the entire page, just remove remote: true from the _form.html.erb

Comment: Hi Aquajach, I tried the code. It works with the change recommended by UKatz below to add the data-sismiss="modal" but it does not save the changes I make. Also the "Add User" button now does not work.

Answer (score 0):

@aquajach has given you the right code to solve your 1st problem. Notice that your problem arose because you did not send the 'user' parameter to the form partial, and instead used `@user` to build the form, which is the variable you initialized in the index action with `new` (so it is empty). As @aquajach did to send the right parameter, you need to place the modal code inside the `.each' loop, otherwise there is no way of telling which user's information you want each modal to display.

Also note that the Edit link_to uses "#" as its url. This means it will link to nowhere, and definitely not go back to the controller on the server (neither to edit, nor to create).

As for your second question. Notice that the Close button has `data-dismiss="modal"`, but the Save Changes button does not. Append that code, to get it to hide the modal as well.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It seems like a lot of duplicate code having the modal repeated for each item. Is there a way of refactoring this code so there is no repetition?

Comment: JavaScript could do that, but it is unnecessary in this case. The only difference between what you are doing & displaying all the information on screen from the start, is that your UI looks better. I would use JavaScript if I did not know how many modals there would be from the start, I had to retrieve new info from the server to display in the modal, or do some other post-render manipulation to the info. There is very little downside to having all this html rendered right away. If the load time is slow because there are too many users, use pagination or something like that.