# How to add a number to a current value in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry for my English.  I have a model with some field. 
How to add a number to a current value in field?
I want to add the number several times

i generated scaffold.I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851955/open-a-bootstrap-modal-to-edit-a-record-in-ruby-on-rails) to create modal. But i want to add number to a current value when i clicked submit

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. When you ask a question, you will receive a much better response if you provide some actual code you have written. Instead of assuming details about your code, we could use your actual approach to solve your question. Hypothetical questions are frowned upon here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@foo = Foo.first 
@foo.bar += 10
#which is a shorter way of saying @foo.bar = @foo.bar + 10
@foo.save
```

If this isn't helpful, please add some more details to your question, eg your example code you have so far.