# How can I store a variable in another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry for my English. I have a Rails app with table Student and modal dialog when i add money to the current balance.
I want to create page Payment where will be stored all information about each student payment

model student.rb

```
 attr_accessor :money

 def add_money
   self.balance += @money.to_i

 end
```

students_controller.rb

```
 def update
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])

  if params[:student].include?(:money)
  if @student.update(student_params)
    @student.add_money
  end
  end
end  

 def payment
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    ....
 end
```

Modal dialog

```
<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :money %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit ("Add"),:class => 'btn' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is "Modal" here?

Comment: I use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851955/open-a-bootstrap-modal-to-edit-a-record-in-ruby-on-rails) to create Bootstrap Modal .

Answer (score 0):

```
attr_accessor :money
   def self.add_money
      self.balance += money.to_i
   end
```

controller

```
   def update
      @student = Student.find(params[:id])
      if params[:student].include?(:money)
          if @student.update(params[:student])
              @student.add_money
          end
      end
  end  

  def payment
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  end
```

and for modal dialog u can refer to [this](http://[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451758/rails-3-2-modal-popup-on-show-action)

Answer (score 0):

if you use

```
   def add_money
      self.balance += money.to_i
   end
```

then in controller use

```
@student.add_money
```